# Hash value of an array containing structs

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, hash

I have a struct called `Survey`. It conforms to both `Equatable` and `Hashable` protocols.

```
import Foundation

public struct Survey {
    public let id: String
    public let createdAt: Date
    public let updatedAt: Date
    public let title: String
    public let type: String
}

extension Survey: Equatable { }

public func ==(lhs: Survey, rhs: Survey) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.createdAt == rhs.createdAt && lhs.updatedAt == rhs.updatedAt && lhs.title == rhs.title && lhs.type == rhs.type
}

extension Survey: Hashable {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        return id.hashValue ^ createdAt.hashValue ^ updatedAt.hashValue ^ title.hashValue ^ type.hashValue
    }
}
```

I can get the hash value of individual `Survey` objects.

But how do I get the hash value of an array containing multiple `Survey` objects?

Comment: Firstly, you can simply do `public struct Survey: Hashable` and get rid of everything else (except the struct variables ofcourse)

Comment: Synthesizing Hashable conformance for arrays is implemented in Swift 4.2: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md

Comment: Secondly, what do you mean `get the hash value of an array containing multiple Survey objects`. Include the expected code that you would like to achieve for this. Something like `[survey_1, survey_N].hashValue`?

Comment: @staticVoidMan yes, that's right.

Comment: @Isuru Then [@Tj3n's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50061402/2857130) has you covered for Swift 4.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
extension Array: Hashable where Iterator.Element: Hashable {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        return self.reduce(1, { $0.hashValue ^ $1.hashValue })
    }
}
```

Custom hash value is just value you define anyway

*Edit: This would also work if you only want `Hashable` for `Survey` array

```
extension Array: Hashable where Element == Survey {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        return self.reduce(1, { $0.hashValue ^ $1.hashValue })
    }
}
```

Comment: you can actually reduce that to `extension Array where Element: Hashable`

Comment: @staticVoidMan I think the OP want to do something with the `Array` that must conform `Hashable` (like using `NSOrderedSet`), so I think its good to keep it

Comment: Noted! My bad :) Extend `Array` to conform to `Hashable` explictly and use the where condition appropriately.